# OP-Amp virtual gnd to real gnd gain control

Tags: operational-amplifier, ground, gain

Can someone please explain why a potentiometer from op-amp virtual ground to real ground control the gain?

Comment: Try writing down the equation for the gain.

Comment: There are many circuit variations that meet your description.  Please post a schematic of *your* circuit with reference designators, so we can discuss individual components.

Comment: Probably (depending on what your circuit actually is) you'll get the (mathematically) correct answer if you assume the op-amp gain is not infinite and offset voltage is not zero. With an ideal op-amp, virtual ground and ground are at the same potential so any non-zero resistance between them has no effect. With a real op-amp it's not like that.

Comment: @medrison please edit your question and draw a circuit diagram with the tool

Answer (score 1):

By attenuating the Vin- feedback to be compared with the Vin+ The output must rise to match the Vin- input , thereby causing gain.  The virtual ground occurs only if the inputs are equal when the output is not saturated at either rail then there is no gain if acts as a comparator.

Answer (score 1):

One can often gain insight into the effect a resistor has on a circuit by thinking about what would happen if the resistor was increased to the point that it becomes an open circuit, and what would happen if the resistor were decreased to the point that it becomes a closed circuit.

Without knowing the exact circuit you are describing, I would assume that with the resistor open, the circuit would just be an amplifier. With the resistor shorted, the inputs of the differential input would be at the same value, and the output would be constant, (in the absence of reactive feedback and such). That is, the gain would be zero.

We can *guess* that with the resistance at some positive finite value, the behavior will be something in between, i.e. amplification, but with a gain somewhat lower than if the resistor were absent.

This technique doesn't always produce correct results, especially if non-linearity is involved, but it is often useful for gaining insight. That insight can be validated (or shown to be in error) by simulating the circuit.

Another approach is to work out the circuit's behavior using KVL and KCL, to get an equation, and then considering what will happen when one of the parameters of the equation are varied.